# Trying to send a transaction with ethers.js

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, sendtransaction

I'm trying to send this transaction using etthers.js and getting transaction details as output but when I try to put the txnhash on etherscan it shows nothing, I tried rinkeby and kovan.
[private key and Web3 provider API keys are hidden]

```
var ethers = require('ethers');  
var url = 'https url of a web3 provider like QuikNode, Infura etc';
var customHttpProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);

var privateKey = "";
var wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
console.log("Address: " + wallet.address);

tx = {
  to: "0x6E0d01A76C3Cf4288372a29124A26D4353EE51BE",
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5"),
  gasLimit: 10000000,
  gasPrice: "0x07f9acf02",
  nonce: 3,
  chainId: 42,
}

wallet.signTransaction(tx).then((signedTX)=>{
    customHttpProvider.sendTransaction(signedTX).then(console.log);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet--methods) (scroll down a bit to the code examples) show that you should be invoking `sendTransaction` on the raw tx object - you don't need to call `signTransaction` first. You can also see this more formally in a little bit above in the docs [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-sendTransaction).

For the record, you mentioned checking Rinkeby for the tx. You've put in `chainId: 42` in the `tx` object, which is Kovan, as you can see [here](https://chainid.network/). I think you already knew that, though, since you mentioned Kovan too.

Another point I can't speak to is if you have to set 'nonce', 'gasPrice', and 'gasLimit' manually. I assume from the Ethers docs code examples that you *don't* (the `tx` object in the example only has `to` and `value`), in which case you most likely should not try setting them yourself, as it will only increase your chances of a failed tx. I'll try to update this if I find out one way or the other.

Comment: If the answer helped you, it helps me if you give the answer an upvote (the up arrow), and accept it as the answer (the checkmark under the up and down arrows). It also signals to people that this answer answered your question, in case they're stuck on a similar problem. No pressure, though! It's your choice to make!